# Can I use SignalR and SQL dependency Without Entity Framework in MVC ?

Tags: c#, sql, model-view-controller, signalr

Can I use SignalR and SQL dependency   Without Entity Framework in MVC ?

Comment: check this http://techbrij.com/database-change-notifications-asp-net-signalr-sqldependency

Comment: Thanks for link its really helpful  i have implemented successfully ..!! How to notify clients using above code..!! I have tried itz goes to infinite loop